# How do I split a routine into threads?

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Timing issue - DGV refreshes before process amends the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9701735/timing-issue-dgv-refreshes-before-process-amends-the-data)

I've got the following code

```
private void btRunReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){ 

    Process p = new Process(); 
    p.StartInfo.FileName = @"\\fileserve\department$\ReportScheduler_v3.exe"; 
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = "12"; 
    p.Start(); 
    p.WaitForExit(); 
    InitializeGridView(); 
}
```

p will update a database table X.
InitializeGridView updates a DGV which reflects table X.

Problem is that if p takes 10minutes to run then the winForm is frozen witing before it hits InitializeGridView(). What I need help with is how do i make the form start the process in a seperate thread that works behind the scenes and runs InitializeGridView() ?

Comment: You can't start a process in a thread as such, that is back to front, and firing off a thread to start the process would be pointless. if you didn't have p.WairForExit your code would continue on to InitializeGridView(); straight away.

Comment: Have a read of [Threading in C#](http://www.albahari.com/threading/) from C# 4.0 in a Nutshell - what you're trying to do is reasonable easy mostly.  **edit**: missed the fact you were trying to run an exe, either way it's a good article

Comment: I think the only way to do this and facilitate safe cancellation is to use a seperate AppDomain...

Comment: Not a duplicate but a follow up question IMHO.

Comment: @till - agreed - the prvious thread cam to an end and this question deserves seperate thread. although think I might have asked this question in the comments of the prev post (I'll delete that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need your InitialilzeGridView() Method to run after the process has finished:

1. Make available `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` as _currentDispatcher.
2. Start the Process in a seperate Thread and have it `WaitForExit()` there.
3. Have the Thread call your `InitializeGridview()` Method via `_currentDispatcher.BeginInvoke`.

Here's some code to get you going:

Note: You will need to add a Reference to WindowsBase via the Add Reference dialog of your project.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Threading;

private readonly Dispatcher _currentDispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
private delegate void ReportingSchedulerFinishedDelegate();

private void btRunReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btRunReport.Enabled = false;
    btRunReport.Text = "Processing..";
    var thread = new Thread(RunReportScheduler);
    thread.Start();
}

private void InitializeGridView()
{
    // Whatever you need to do here
}

private void RunReportScheduler()
{
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.FileName = @"\\fileserve\department$\ReportScheduler_v3.exe";
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = "12";
    p.Start();
    p.WaitForExit();
    _currentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(new ReportingSchedulerFinishedDelegate(ReportingSchedulerFinished), DispatcherPriority.Normal);
}

private void ReportingSchedulerFinished()
{
    InitializeGridView();
    btRunReport.Enabled = true;
    btRunReport.Text = "Start";
}
```

Comment: Till - your solution seems to works perfectly - I just need to research it to find out how it works now!

Comment: It's pretty straight forward: run the long running RunReportSchedule in its own thread. Problem with a background thread is that you may not access elements handled by your main GUI thread directly. _currentDispatcher will hold a reference to the dispatcher from your GUI thread and to that you can pass the instruction to run ReportSchedulerFinished via a delegate after it has finished to prepare the data.